# Is there a way to set an observer on any ember model change in ember store?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

First of all, I am using ember 2.
I am requesting the back-end and it returns some data. Then, I pushed these data to a model in ember store. The issue that I want to do some action when this model is updated. So, Is there a way to observe the model in the store?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findAll` returns live array, so we can have dependent key for the findAll result so that our observer/computed properties will be triggered every time stores model changes.

```
 userModel:Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('user');
  }),

 userModelObserver: Ember.observer('userModel.[]',function(){
    console.log('observer triggered');
  }),
```

May be this is not the ideal solution.

Comment: Thank you man, that works fine with me.
But I want to know how it works. In my perspective I think that the observer will call computed till it has been changed. Is that right?

Comment: yes. `findAll` returns `Promise` response and it will be resolved to `RecordArray`, and we are observing that RecordArray changes..  By default `findAll` will be in sync with store. which means whenever store updated this live arrays too updaed.