# Ember sentry/raven: set user context when user model loads?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, sentry, raven

**% Preamble %**

I am setting up ember-cli-sentry and am looking to identify the user so that when we get exceptions reported, we know what user those exceptions were associated with, in case they were user-specific. (Say, we deploy to staging, we got some data from the backend that was bad, causing certain errors with the only the users who got that bad data into their account).

**& Actual question &**

I want to execute some code immediately after the user model loads. I do not know what route is going to be triggering the user model to load.

In theory, actually, the earliest possible place I could get the user model data is immediately after the request for that data is completed. I wonder, would it be crazy to hijack the XHR method, and when the user id is requested, run my code to tell raven/sentry who this user is?

It would be better if there was simply a "loaded" hook for model files, but I've never heard of such a thing. Maybe this is the one use case where this would be desirable?

An h1 for google/seo:

## Ember:Hook to execute code after model loads from any route? How do I execute code after model loads from any route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @duizendnegen and @Isaac Askew, observers were a great starting point and led me to the final solution. This observer code, placed in my application route, helped me figure out exactly what I *could* add as user context:

```
window.serviceState = {};
// eslint-disable-next-line
let serviceState = window.serviceState;

export default Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  // observes services for state changes we care about and stores them in
  // a separate variable so when an exception occurs, we can simply include that
  // variable and avoid the risk of causing another exception by trying
  // to read them in `captureException`
  serviceStateTracker: observer(
    'service1.prop1',
    'service2.propA',
    function() {
      [
        'service1.prop1',
        'service2.propA',
      ].forEach((prop) => {
        let newValue = this.get(prop);
        if (serviceState[prop] !== newValue) {
          if (serviceState[prop] === undefined) {
            console.log(prop, newValue);
          } else {
            console.log(prop, 'changed from:', serviceState[prop], 'to:', newValue);
          }
          serviceState[prop] = newValue;
        }
      });
    }
  ),
```

However, I did try just `get`ing the props I care about in my `logger` service at exception time instead, and this worked well. It's better because you won't have code needlessly executing every time a property you want to log changes:

```
// app/services/logr.js
// initially generated with ember-cli-sentry's `ember g logger logr`
import RavenLogger from 'ember-cli-deploy-sentry/services/raven';
import Ember from 'ember';

const { Logger, inject: { service } } = Ember;

export default RavenLogger.extend({

  unhandledPromiseErrorMessage: '',
  user: service(),
  i18n: service(),

  addContext() {
    if (this == null) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.warn('logr cannot addContext because this is null/undefined, continuing without');
      return;
    }
    let tagsContext = {
      locale: this.get('i18n.locale'),
      id: this.get('user.id'),
      firstName: this.get('user.firstName'),
      lastName: this.get('user.lastName'),
      email: this.get('user.email')
    };
    // console.log('tagsContext', tagsContext);
    // For some reason setUserContext was not working, but setTagsContext was,
    // so I am using tags for all the user info. Maybe upgrading raven could fix this?
    this.callRaven('setTagsContext', tagsContext);
    // why use callRaven: https://github.com/damiencaselli/ember-cli-sentry/issues/58
  },

  // work around for unmerged PR:
  // https://github.com/damiencaselli/ember-cli-sentry/pull/97
  captureException(/* error */) {
    if (this.get('isRavenUsable')) {
      this.addContext();
      window.Raven.captureException(...arguments);
    } else {
      Logger.debug(...arguments);
    }
    return true;
  },

  captureMessage(/* message */) {
    if (this.get('isRavenUsable')) {
      this.addContext();
      window.Raven.captureMessage(...arguments);
    } else {
      Logger.debug(...arguments);
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

For some reason the observer wouldn't work in my logr service..

### Extra notes:

- with the ember-cli-deploy-sentry addon, don't forget to put THAT config in `config/DEPLOY.js`, not `config/environment.js`

To trigger an error somewhere in some application route hook:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // I was having some issue with `throw new Error()` so I did this instead
  // It's actually just a better way to manually 'throw an exception'
  // because it will not forcibly crash the application, but instead
  // at least attempt to continue running
  this.get('logr').captureException(new Error('sentry user context test'));
}, 10000);
```

- Don't forget to set `development: false` to let raven actually send this test error to sentry (unless you aren't testing end to end) (I typically have this set: `development: environment === 'development'`

In application route actions, add this to your error action handler:

```
error(error) {
  // Trap unhandled failures during routing:
  // Should maybe be handled by the sentry addon, but is not as of now:
  // https://github.com/damiencaselli/ember-cli-sentry/issues/105
  this.get('logr').captureException(error);
```

Comment: Note: calling logr.captureException in or before app route init hook (before raven is setup) https://github.com/damiencaselli/ember-cli-sentry/issues/164

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in your [main application route](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_the-application-route) you can do something like this:

```
user: alias('model')

userModelLoaded: observer('user.id', function() {
  // execute code to set up Raven
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to either

- set up an Observer on your Ember Data store - [Is there a way to set an observer on any ember model change in ember store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851742/is-there-a-way-to-set-an-observer-on-any-ember-model-change-in-ember-store) - but this seems finicky, or;
- after the log in route calls back, set the context:

---

```
Raven.setUserContext({
    email: 'matt@example.com',
    id: '123'
});
```